# Get all PrettyFaces mapping ids before FacesContext is available?

Tags: prettyfaces

I need to test some strings against the existing mapping ids, I would like to get all the mapping ids before runtime (statically), is this possible ?

In theory PrettyFaces would only have to parse the pretty-config.xml in order to allow this, but currently calling `PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getConfig().getMappings()` will fail as the faces context is not available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you should use: `PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance(final HttpServletRequest request)`

This will give you access to the configuration without using `.getCurrentInstance()` - which is only one way of obtaining the PrettyContext, and happens to require an active FacesContext.

Comment: I did not notice there were other ways to get that current instance, this is quite nice.